# Can I open MS Office PowerPoint presentations in Ubuntu?

Tags: libreoffice

If I install Ubuntu can I load and use my original Microsoft PowerPoint presentation on the Ubuntu OS and use the slideshow features to give a presentation?  Is it also possible to easily convert the Microsoft PowerPoint presentation into the Ubuntu format and present it that way.

Comment: Ubuntu has Libreoffice installed which can open and show MS Powerpoint files. It's not 100% compatible though. If you have a MS Office licence, it is possible to install it through Wine.

Comment: Thank you for the great response Seth. It's a 76 page PowerPoint so converting it would be much better than redoing it.  I'm wiping my PC because of malicious software. If I do as you suggest with the USB trial, without wiping my PC first will I risk contaminating the Ubunto OS. I have Microsoft 7 and Office 2010 available. To be safe, should I install MS software using wine first before the Ubuntu or the other way around if I decide to use both operating systems?  Will the wine software be self-explanatory and take me through the process to install MS operating system?

Comment: My PowerPoint uses a "papyrus" Microsoft font. Does Ubuntu use the papyrus font?

Comment: Yeah sure, you can install any TTF font to use with any application in Ubuntu - just open the .TTF file with a double click and choose "Install" from the bottom right button. I just tested this for Impress, it seems to fully support the Papyrus font. Running Office applications in Wine (or Windows in a virtual machine) is more like a last resort when conversion completely failed.

Comment: Your explanation really helped.  You confirmed what I suspected that I don't need the Microsoft office suite and will do very well with Ununtu. I'll follow your other suggestions and do a trial first. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the answer solved your question, please mark the answer as an "Accepted Answer" by clicking on the tick sign below the question's votes.

Answer (score 7):

The use of Microsoft Power Point presentations is supported by default in Ubuntu. After a fresh installation you will also have Libre Office installed.

This office suite comes with Impress, a presentation software similar to Power Point. With Impress you can not only import and view presentations including slide shows but you will also be able to export your presentations to Power Point format for use in a Windows computer.

- Read more on Impress here: [Libre Office - Impress](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/impress/)

Having said that, we need to address possible issues than may arise from converting Power Point to Impress which eventually need some fine tuning after importing:

- special effects or transitions may not always work as expected
- the page layout may vary when using fonts not available on Ubuntu (we can, however install the MS Core Fonts for free, and any other TTF fonts)
- multiple images may not be perfectly arranged

Therefore, and because we do not really know much on the presentations you have, the best approach is to just try this out. You do not have to install Ubuntu to do this. It is perfectly fine to boot your computer with an Ubuntu CD (or USB).

**Instead of installing choose to *"Try out Ubuntu"*.**

Your hard drive will not be touched but you will have access to your local hard drives when opening them through the file browser Nautilus (folder icon on the left side launcher).

Your Power Point presentations can then be opened on double click with Impress.